# Sublime plugin for get parent key name

Tags: json, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

If I have a JSON file (`config.json`) with sample content:

```
"A" : {
  ...
  "B" : "valuIe"| //cursor here
  ...
  },
"C": {
  ...
  "B": "value",
  ...
}
```

}

If I have a cursor in a child object key, I want to know I'm in the position **A > B** and not C > B. This is really helpful in large JSON file like configuration files.

Is there a Sublime text plugin to show the same just like in Webstorm below?

[image: Webstorm]